# style.css not accepted by server

Tags: html, css

I set up my website locally on my hard disk, and everything works fine.
But when I upload my website to the server, the file "style.css" is not loaded.

When I look at code (F12), it gives me:
"style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

The HTML file looks like this:

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Child-Abduction.net</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="verify-v1" content="L0UzG/4pPu9fgnLL3FmaFIzGkaVSoAgVZ9LHzQ0yx0c=" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="favicon/ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Any idea why "style.css" refuses to load on my website?

TIA

Comment: Is the css file at the same directory as this file

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing the details (are you hosting the application in ASP.NET or other technology?). Maybe try if any error is displayed by entering the address yourdomain.com/style.css? In my opinion, you have a problem with the configuration file on the server

Comment: How are you uploading it? FTP? cPanel? Some other interface?

Answer (score 0):

Found what was causing the "error".
Seemed that several other files were not accepted by the server although on my notebook everything worked fine.
For some reason, EVERYTHING that's uploaded to the server needs to be in "lower case".
Uploaded also some *.JPG files that were not accepted by the server until I changed them into *.jpg.
Thanks